# Managed C++ WPF programatically ListBoxItem style resource adding is not working

Tags: wpf, c++-cli

I know this is probably absolutely crazy what I am doing but it is the circumstances that kind of do not leave me any other options right now. 
I am putting together a WPF UI using C++/CLI without XAML connected to unmanaged/PURE C++ Direct3D11 elements and it all kind of works as long as you do not stray into the area of UI templates/styling.

However in one part of the UI I really need to change the color of the selected and hover-selected item(s) of a ListBox away from the default windows style the cient simply does not like that bluish colour.

I tried following code but it has zero effect:

```
System::Windows::Style^ s = gcnew System::Windows::Style((gcnew System::Windows::Controls::ListBoxItem())->GetType());
s->Resources->Add(SystemColors::HighlightBrushKey, gcnew SolidColorBrush(System::Windows::Media::Color::FromRgb(255,0,0)));
s->Resources->Add(SystemColors::ControlBrushKey, gcnew SolidColorBrush(System::Windows::Media::Color::FromRgb(255, 0, 0)));
ListBox^ filelist = gcnew ListBox();
filelist->ItemContainerStyle = s;
```

But this does basically nothing also assigning the style to the ->FocusVisualStyle property of the ListBox does nothing

Any suggestions on what to do or how to get this working without resorting to XAML resource

Update: It looks like this code works at least partially under Windows 7 but does not do anything under Windows 10 ???

Comment: Why can't you put the Managed C++ elements inside their own assembly and write the UI as a separate project?

Comment: @BenCottrell: What issue would that solve? Placing the managed portion of a C++/CLI assembly into its own assembly pretty much defies the purpose of C++/CLI, to easily bridge between managed and unmanaged/native code.

Comment: @IInspectable Am I right in thinking that the reason you're avoiding writing the WPF app using XAML is that your code uses Managed C++?   You can import any Managed C++ class library assembly into any kind of .NET application, including one which uses XAML.

Comment: @BenCottrell: I don't know, what the OP's rationale is for choosing this strategy. At any rate, they aren't using Managed C++. They are using C++/CLI. Not sure this makes any difference, but I have no hands-on experience with Managed C++.

Comment: @IInspectable Sorry about that, I thought you were the OP for some reason.    Managed C++ is an alternative name for C++/CLI, but in any case, a typical use for C++/CLI is to create a class library containing wrappers for native code which can then be used in a .NET application, meaning that the .NET Application itself has no idea it's talking to Native code - e.g.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/dotnet/how-to-wrap-native-class-for-use-by-csharp

Comment: [Managed C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C%2B%2B) was a different (now deprecated) C++ extension to target the .NET runtime. It was superseded by C++/CLI in 2004. I'm still not sure, what issue your initial comment addresses, or how it solves it. The OP could be asking to solve the wrong issue altogether. I don't know about that. But if they want to avoid XAML, then they can. Anything that can be done in XAML can be done in code, too. Even if cumbersome.

Comment: @BenCottrel: Sorry it is not .NET application it is a .NET UI-Window hosted in a Win32 native window and which that is also having a Direct3D11 component. So although it might be technical possible to load in XAML resources it looks like an equal painful thing to do just for this little thing.

Comment: @IInspectable indeed, the fact that it is cumbersome is usually a problem in itself.  I realise that anything which is doable in XAML can also be done in any other .NET language, but XAML is usually the easiest way.